# Powershell poor StringBuilder performance?

Tags: sql, string, powershell, sqlite, stringbuilder

I'm trying to build queries so I can insert large amounts of data into an sqlite3 table. I've tried several methods of doing this, including [PSSQLite](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSSQLite) which should be able to take a DataTable and insert it with ease. Even with only 10,000 records it takes nearly 40 minutes to run and I have no clue why.

My other option is to build a query and execute it using another method such as Invoke-Sqlcmd. I've tried doing this with a StringBuilder except that it's taking over 2 minutes to build the string. Like I said, it's only 10,000 records so from what I've ready it should only take 10-15 seconds TOPS. Considering I have, at minimum, several million records to import I really need this to go faster.

Here is the code I'm using. Am I just missing something here?

```bsh
$sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
$sb.AppendLine("BEGIN TRANSACTION")
foreach ($document in $documents) {
   
  $null = $sb.AppendLine("INSERT or IGNORE into documents(DocId,Submid,docno,Tray,Pieceno,CreateDate,Account,AccName,AccAddr1,AccAddr2,AccAddr3,AccAddr4,AccCity,AccState,AccZip,BCDP,BarcodeID,ServTypeID,Mailerid,SerialNo,Sys_Name,Sys_Addr1,Sys_Addr2,Sys_Addr3,Sys_Addr4,Sys_City,Sys_State,Sys_Zip)");
  $null = $sb.AppendLine("VALUES('$($document.DocId)','$($document.Submid)','$($document.docno)','$($document.Tray)','$($document.Pieceno)','$($document.CreateDate)','$($document.Account)','$($document.AccName)','$($document.AccAddr1)','$($document.AccAddr2)','$($document.AccAddr3)','$($document.AccAddr4)','$($document.AccCity)','$($document.AccState)','$($document.AccZip)','$($document.BCDP)','$($document.BarcodeID)','$($document.ServTypeID)','$($document.Mailerid)','$($document.SerialNo)','$($document.Sys_Name)','$($document.Sys_Addr1)','$($document.Sys_Addr2)','$($document.Sys_Addr3)','$($document.Sys_Addr4)','$($document.Sys_City)','$($document.Sys_State)','$($document.Sys_Zip)')")
    
}
    
$sb.AppendLine("COMMIT")
$query = $sb.ToString();
#Invoke-SqliteQuery $ref_db $query #commenting this out, because I haven't even attempted the insert because StringBuilder is not optimized enough yet.
```

In this instance, $documents is a generic object containing each of the fields in the INSERT statement. Most of the fields are populated with a string, which some are blank.

#EDIT: I'm running this in Powershell ISE with breakpoints set, would that cause the performance issues?

Comment: Is this actually stringbuilder performance? Or rather PSqlite performance?

Comment: It could be because pssqlite tries to fill a result set, I don't see a non-query option(?)

Comment: I'd suggest building a SQL statement that inserts multiple records at one time.  And I'd always use a stored procedure instead of data that provided by the user.

Comment: I edited my question because it was misleading. I haven't even ran the query I've created using StringBuilder because it's so slow that it won't work for my needs. Building the query itself is taking way too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before getting to the `StringBuilder` aspect of your question, let's look at SQLite:

I'd expect you to see a difference in processing time if you change the SQL to commit a *single* multi-row `INSERT` statement, instead of 10000 separate `INSERT`'s, as you're doing now - in other words:

```
$null = $sb.AppendLine("INSERT or IGNORE into documents(DocId,Submid,docno,Tray,Pieceno,CreateDate,Account,AccName,AccAddr1,AccAddr2,AccAddr3,AccAddr4,AccCity,AccState,AccZip,BCDP,BarcodeID,ServTypeID,Mailerid,SerialNo,Sys_Name,Sys_Addr1,Sys_Addr2,Sys_Addr3,Sys_Addr4,Sys_City,Sys_State,Sys_Zip)")
$null = $sb.AppendLine("VALUES")

foreach ($document in $documents) {
  # Add separate value tuple for each document, add trailing `,`
  $null = $sb.AppendLine("('$($document.DocId)','$($document.Submid)','$($document.docno)','$($document.Tray)','$($document.Pieceno)','$($document.CreateDate)','$($document.Account)','$($document.AccName)','$($document.AccAddr1)','$($document.AccAddr2)','$($document.AccAddr3)','$($document.AccAddr4)','$($document.AccCity)','$($document.AccState)','$($document.AccZip)','$($document.BCDP)','$($document.BarcodeID)','$($document.ServTypeID)','$($document.Mailerid)','$($document.SerialNo)','$($document.Sys_Name)','$($document.Sys_Addr1)','$($document.Sys_Addr2)','$($document.Sys_Addr3)','$($document.Sys_Addr4)','$($document.Sys_City)','$($document.Sys_State)','$($document.Sys_Zip)'),")
}
    
# trim trailing newline + comma on last insert value before adding COMMIT statement
$query = $sb.ToString().TrimEnd("`r`n,") + "`r`nCOMMIT"
Invoke-SqliteQuery $ref_db $query
```

---

There's a minuscule optimization to be had by avoiding expandable strings and instead using `$sb.AppendFormat()`, ie.:

```
$sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
$sb.AppendLine("BEGIN TRANSACTION")
$null = $sb.AppendFormat('VALUES ({0}, {2}, ...)', $doc.DocId, $doc.SubmId, ...).AppendLine()
```

... but that's likely not the issue.

In *Windows* PowerShell, string manipulation (whether through direct concatenation or with a string build) have some [very funky performance characteristics](https://powershell.one/tricks/performance/strings) as soon as the size exceeds the threshold for the Large Object Heap cache (85Kb) in .NET Framework.

This does *not* seem to occur in .NET Core, so upgrading to a newer version of PowerShell (such as PowerShell 7) might prove to eliminate this problem all together.

If you need to target Windows PowerShell, you might want to simply write your SQL script directly to disk and read it back with `Invoke-SqliteQuery -InputFile`:

```
$scriptFile = New-Item import.sql

try{
  $fileWriter = $scriptFile.CreateText()
  $fileWriter.WriteLine("INSERT or IGNORE into documents(DocId,Submid,docno,Tray,Pieceno,CreateDate,Account,AccName,AccAddr1,AccAddr2,AccAddr3,AccAddr4,AccCity,AccState,AccZip,BCDP,BarcodeID,ServTypeID,Mailerid,SerialNo,Sys_Name,Sys_Addr1,Sys_Addr2,Sys_Addr3,Sys_Addr4,Sys_City,Sys_State,Sys_Zip)")

  foreach ($document in $documents) {
    $fileWriter.WriteLine("VALUES")
    $fileWriter.WriteLine("('$($document.DocId)','$($document.Submid)','$($document.docno)','$($document.Tray)','$($document.Pieceno)','$($document.CreateDate)','$($document.Account)','$($document.AccName)','$($document.AccAddr1)','$($document.AccAddr2)','$($document.AccAddr3)','$($document.AccAddr4)','$($document.AccCity)','$($document.AccState)','$($document.AccZip)','$($document.BCDP)','$($document.BarcodeID)','$($document.ServTypeID)','$($document.Mailerid)','$($document.SerialNo)','$($document.Sys_Name)','$($document.Sys_Addr1)','$($document.Sys_Addr2)','$($document.Sys_Addr3)','$($document.Sys_Addr4)','$($document.Sys_City)','$($document.Sys_State)','$($document.Sys_Zip)')")
    $fileWriter.WriteLine("")
  }
  $fileWriter.WriteLine("COMMIT")
}
finally{
  $fileWriter.Close()
}    

Invoke-SqliteQuery $ref_db -InputFile import.sql
```

Comment: I may need to reword my question. I have two performance issues:
1. when using PSSQLite to directly insert my query results (which are already in DataTable format) 
2. when building the query manually via StringBuilder. I haven't even ran this query yet, because I can't optimize the stringbuilder to where it won't take forever

Comment: @fudge You claim in the question that it takes 2 minutes - if you want a faster test, try with 1000 documents instead. It might also be useful to let us know where `$documents` came from?

Comment: I'm just seeing poor performance compared to what should be possible here: https://powershell.one/tricks/performance/strings
I think it may just be the reality of what I'm trying to do. This may just be a slow operation

Comment: @fudge if you scroll down to the bottom of that page, you'll find it actually quotes me for pointing out this only occurs when the string length exceeds a certain length (seems to be the Large Object Heap cache threshold of 85KB). `Measure-Script` might help you determine if this is what you're seeing as well

Comment: That's what I get for skimming the article!! Yes, that is exactly what the problem is. I was able to solve this by simply upgrading to the PS v7. It went from 20 minutes to 2 seconds. How can I credit you for this? Maybe I will mark your answer and edit it to include these details.

Comment: @fudge Sorry for the delay, answer is updated now :)

Comment: No worries, thank you for all you do. If you weren't here I'd still be scratching my head.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just using the PowerShell way using the Pipeline and the [`-Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-7) operator?

```
$sb = ($Documents | Foreach { "BEGIN TRANSACTION" }  {
          "INSERT or IGNORE into documents(DocId,Submid,docno,Tray,Pieceno,CreateDate,Account,AccName,AccAddr1,AccAddr2,AccAddr3,AccAddr4,AccCity,AccState,AccZip,BCDP,BarcodeID,ServTypeID,Mailerid,SerialNo,Sys_Name,Sys_Addr1,Sys_Addr2,Sys_Addr3,Sys_Addr4,Sys_City,Sys_State,Sys_Zip)"
          "VALUES('$($_.DocId)','$($_.Submid)','$($_.docno)','$($_.Tray)','$($_.Pieceno)','$($_.CreateDate)','$($_.Account)','$($_.AccName)','$($_.AccAddr1)','$($_.AccAddr2)','$($_.AccAddr3)','$($_.AccAddr4)','$($_.AccCity)','$($_.AccState)','$($_.AccZip)','$($_.BCDP)','$($_.BarcodeID)','$($_.ServTypeID)','$($_.Mailerid)','$($_.SerialNo)','$($_.Sys_Name)','$($_.Sys_Addr1)','$($_.Sys_Addr2)','$($_.Sys_Addr3)','$($_.Sys_Addr4)','$($_.Sys_City)','$($_.Sys_State)','$($_.Sys_Zip)')"
    } { "COMMIT" }) -Join [Environment]::NewLine
```

Or (as the `Foreach` statement usually tends a little bit faster than the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet):

```
$sb = @(
    "BEGIN TRANSACTION"
    foreach ($document in $documents) {
      "INSERT or IGNORE into documents(DocId,Submid,docno,Tray,Pieceno,CreateDate,Account,AccName,AccAddr1,AccAddr2,AccAddr3,AccAddr4,AccCity,AccState,AccZip,BCDP,BarcodeID,ServTypeID,Mailerid,SerialNo,Sys_Name,Sys_Addr1,Sys_Addr2,Sys_Addr3,Sys_Addr4,Sys_City,Sys_State,Sys_Zip)"
      "VALUES('$($_.DocId)','$($_.Submid)','$($_.docno)','$($_.Tray)','$($_.Pieceno)','$($_.CreateDate)','$($_.Account)','$($_.AccName)','$($_.AccAddr1)','$($_.AccAddr2)','$($_.AccAddr3)','$($_.AccAddr4)','$($_.AccCity)','$($_.AccState)','$($_.AccZip)','$($_.BCDP)','$($_.BarcodeID)','$($_.ServTypeID)','$($_.Mailerid)','$($_.SerialNo)','$($_.Sys_Name)','$($_.Sys_Addr1)','$($_.Sys_Addr2)','$($_.Sys_Addr3)','$($_.Sys_Addr4)','$($_.Sys_City)','$($_.Sys_State)','$($_.Sys_Zip)')"
    }
    "COMMIT"
) -Join [Environment]::NewLine
```